# Como adaptar / criar um método que receba uma classe anônima em C#

Tags: c#, classes, expressões-lambda, genéricos, polimorfismo

Possuo um método no qual um dos parâmetros é um objeto de uma classe abstrata - ObjectMapper - cujo propósito é converter um objeto de uma classe em outro de outra classe. Abaixo, a assinatura do método informa que o objectMapper receberá como entrada um DbDataReader e retornará um objeto genérico T

```
public T Select<T>(string query, ObjectMapper<T, DbDataReader> objectMapper)
{
    var reader = dbConnector.CreateCommand(query).ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        return objectMapper.from(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Como venho do background Java, para os casos que não necessito criar uma classe, bastaria usar uma classe anônima. No entanto, parece que o C# não provê essa funcionalidade, de forma que eu pudesse invocar o método como a seguir

```
Select<Pessoa>("SELECT * FROM PESSOA", new ObjectMapper<Pessoa, DbDataReader>() {
    public override Pessoa from(DbDataReader reader) {
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();

        /** Populo o objeto p a partir do objeto DbDataReader **/

        return p;
    }
});
```

O que deve fazer para adaptar - ou até mesmo criar um novo método - de forma que eu possa passar uma "classe anônima" para o método Select ?

**UPDATE**

Segue a classe ObjectMapper

```
public abstract class ObjectMapper<T, Source>
{
    public abstract T from(Source source);

    public static bool hasColumnName(DbDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (reader.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /** Outros métodos utilitários **/ 
}
```

Essa classe seria uma adaptação da classe RowMapper, usado pelo Spring framework

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/

Comment: Na verdade provê sim, mas queria entender de onde vem esse `ObjectMapper`. É de algum ORM?

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez Não cigano. Vou postar a classe

Comment: A classe *ObjectMapper* tem mais algum método *abstract*? O método `Select` necessita da classe *ObjectMapper* ou apenas de aceder ao método `from`?

Comment: @ramaral Abstrato só o método from. O método Select necessita apenas acessar o método from. Os métodos utilitários geralmente são acessados pelas instâncias da classe ObjectMapper

Comment: O método `from` acede a algum método/propriedade de *ObjectMapper*?

Comment: @ramaral As classes que herdam ObjectMapper - e consequentemente implementam o método from - podem acessar métodos estáticos da classe ObjectMapper, como o hasColumnName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em C# você pode recorrer a um *delegate* para passar uma função/método a outro método.

O C# disponibiliza alguns *delegates* prontos a usar.

Se apenas necessita de utilizar métodos estáticos da classe *ObjectMapper* sugiro que faça assim:

Declare o método `Select` da seguite forma:

```
public T Select<T>(string query, Func<DbDataReader, T> from)
{
    var reader = dbConnector.CreateCommand(query).ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        return from(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Ao método `Select`, além da string correspondente à SQL, é passado um *delegate* que recebe um *DbDataReader* e retorna um objecto do tipo `T`

Esse delegate é encapsulado recorrendo a [`Func<T, TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Para chamar o método `Select` faça assim:

```
Pessoa pessoa = Select("SELECT * FROM PESSOA", reader =>
    {
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();

        /** Populo o objeto p a partir do objeto DbDataReader **/

        return p;
    });
```

O código entre chavetas é como quiser e dentro dele você tem acesso ao *DbDataReader* através da variável `reader`

Answer (score 1):

Se o objetivo é providenciar um mapeador dinâmico para C#, já existem alguns prontos, [como o AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/).

Se o objetivo é implementar para aprender, posso dizer que nunca vi esta construção de definir o objeto e aí implementar o corpo da função, tudo junto, pelo menos não em C#.

No seu lugar, não definiria `from` como abstrato. Definiria `virtual`, permitindo às classes derivadas reimplementar o método caso necessário:

```
public abstract class ObjectMapper<T, TSource>
    where T: class, new()
    where TSource: DbDataReader
{
    public IEnumerable<T> From(TSource source)
    {
        if (source.HasRows)
        {
            while (source.Read())
            {
                var objeto = new T();
                for( int index = 0; index < source.FieldCount; index ++ )
                {
                    typeof(T).GetProperty(source.GetName(index)).SetValue(objeto, source.GetString(index));
                }

                yield return objeto;
            }
         }
    };

    public static bool hasColumnName(DbDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (reader.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /** Outros métodos utilitários **/ 
}
```

Este exemplo não está exatamente seguro, mas seria um começo.

Comment: Na verdade, fiz uma adaptação do RowMapper, usado pelo Spring framework. Ver http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/

Comment: Bom, para fins didáticos acho válido, mas o C# tem outras maneiras mais interessantes de obter dados e mapear para objetos que usando um `DbDataReader`. O micro-framework [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), usado para implementar este site em que estamos, é uma delas.